# Serilog Console sink output newline as \r\n

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, asp.net-core-5.0

I am using `Serilog` logger together with a Console sink to do logging in my `ASP.NET Core 5.0` project. Also use the same `ILoggerFactory` with EF Core 5.0 like below

```
optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(serilogFactory)
```

But when EF Core logs SQL statements, the lines are not shown as linebreak on the console, instead it is shown as `\r\n` instead.
But if I use the builtin `LoggerFactory` from `ASP.NET Core` like below

```
var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(
    builder => builder.AddConsole(options =>
    {
    })
);
optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory);
```

Then it's fine.

Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using Serilog with the Console Sink the `Message` property in the Template should have the format specifier `:l` to achieve the desired format:

```json
"outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {Message:l}{NewLine}{Exception}"
```

By using that specifier the message string won't be quoted, thus formatting the output correctly.

More info about specifiers: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output

Comment: thanks for this. This is very useful!